# MariaDB to calculate table reference in select query

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a quite dumb client application that wants to get information from MariaDB based on a parameter.
This parameter is a string that contains spaces, like 'valid parameter'.
In MariaDB there is a table for each of the possible string values, and the table name is the string value after spaces have been replaced by underscores and a prefix is added. So I can perform the necessary conversion like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('prefix_', REPLACE('valid parameter',' ','_'));
```

Now the result 'prefix_valid_parameter' is the table to query, so actually I need to fire off

```
SELECT * from CONCAT('prefix_', REPLACE('valid parameter',' ','_'));
```

but MariaDB responds with

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '('prefix_', REPLACE('valid parameter',' ','_'))' at line 1
```

I would have expected either the content of table 'prefix_valid_parameter' or an error stating "table 'prefix_valid_parameter' not found". How can I make the table_reference part of my [SQL SELECT statement](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/select/) dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use dynamic SQL:

```
set @sql = 'select * from [table]';

execute immediate replace(@sql, '[table]',
                          concat('prefix_', replace('valid parameter', ' ', '_'))
                         );
```

I should add that the need to do this perhaps suggests a flaw in your data model.  If the tables have the same structure, it is better to put all the rows in a single table.

Comment: The tables have a few common columns, but most of them are special. Hence the decision to have the in separate tables.

Comment: It works in a proper SQL client. But for crying out loud: My dumb client is Grafana, and this one neither can manipulate string values itself (https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/8259) nor can it pass the job to MariaDB using dynamic SQL (https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/8755). I am speechless.

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri . . . Perhaps you should ask another question about Grafana and dynamic SQL.

Comment: I already placed my comments on the two relevant github entries - both are referenced in my above comment. But thank you for the hint. :-)